# Laravel 4 resource controllers - Unable to generate a URL for the named rout

Tags: resources, laravel, controllers

Dead simple this one but maybe it cant be done who knows... i have created a resourceful controller named books but i want to group the books resource (and some others i have created, like cd resource etc) and prefix them with MyStuff. like below

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'MyStuff','before' => 'auth','after' => 'log'), function()
{
    Route::resource('books', 'BooksController');
});
//Unable to generate a URL for the named route "books.create" as such route does not exist.
```

But as you can see i get an error message saying

Unable to generate a URL for the named route "books.create" as such route does not exist.

if i just try and run

```
Route::resource('books', 'BooksController');
```

it all works fine of course. can you not group and then prefix resourceful controllers?

Even

```
Route::resource('mystuff/books', 'BooksController');
```

does not work, i get the same error message?

Comment: I think I had something similar the other day - does the route `MyStuff.books.create` work? I think it appends the group prefix to the contained routes.

Comment: **Prepends** the group prefix, rather.

Comment: ao are you suggesting in my controller i see if i can load a route MyStuff.books.create if so the answer to your question is no it doesnt work! Thanks for your suggestions so far

Comment: Ah i have found the answer, there are a lot of references to 'route MyStuff.books.create' that i didnt see, i will have to go through my boilerplate code and update them with the prefix MyStuff.books.create from what is there now which is just books.create. Thank you much apreciated

Comment: No problem :) Just to let you know, in case you try to alias a group (i.e. `['as' => 'somethingelse']`), you'll fall into [this bug](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1742)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `URL::action`? Try: `URL::action('BooksController@METHODNAME')`

See: http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Routing.UrlGenerator.html#230-264

Keep in mind resource controllers have several types of actions AND route names: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: +1 this works great! Also is there  a way to name routes for Resource Controllers? I tried using the same convention as routes but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can check all available routes in your app by running artisan command `php artisan routes`

Answer (score 0):

do this

`{{ route('MyStaff.books.index }}`

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
{{ route('MyStaff.books.index') }}
```